# git log pretty format with %cI placeholder returns "cI" instead of the commit date

Tags: windows, git, centos, format

I'm running a script to get commit data of some repositories in a server.
The git command I am using is this:

```
git log HEAD -1 --pretty=%H~%h~%cI~%cE~%cn~%s
```

It works perfectly on my windows pc, but in my server with CentOS, it prints the string "cI" instead of the formated ISO date.

Result on Windows PC:

```
40c688e4976d28a560f5711e73c2a933da3cfbbe~40c688e~2021-07-02T17:18:48-04:00~usertest@mail.com~gituser1~Commit into master
```

Result on CentOS server same repository:

```
40c688e4976d28a560f5711e73c2a933da3cfbbe~40c688e~cI~usertest@mail.com~gituser1~Commit into master
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
Im using git version 2.30.0.windows.2 on windows and git version 1.8.3.1 on CentOS

Comment: Go for `--pretty=format:"%H~%h~%cI~%cE~%cn~%s"`

Comment: @RomainValeri Hhank you for your comment!. Sadly I got the same result.

Comment: Is that a capital i or a lower-case L?

Comment: @eftshift0 its a capital i, it should print the date on strict ISO 8601 format

Comment: It is working for me, I guess: `~2021-07-09T12:30:15-06:00~`. That's on a mac. On a debian VM (with `testing`): `~2021-07-09T18:27:00+00:00` (another revision so information is ok to not be the same). What git versions are you using in each box?

Comment: @eftshift0 Im using git version 1.8.3.1 on CentOS and git version 2.30.0.windows.2 on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than likely due to the fact that you are using a version of git on centos that didn't support `--pretty=%cI`. Consider updating it. I might be wrong but I think it showed up in git in version `v2.2.0`. https://github.com/git/git/commit/466fb6742d7fb7d3e6994b2d0d8db83a8786ebcf

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems like the CentOS server is running Centos7 for some reason, and the latest "supported" version was 1.8.3.1 so I couldn't update git automatically to the lastest version.